# Uber iOS Integration Access Token Missing

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I have created a developer account in Uber, got the client ID.
Configured the following setting in `info.plist`

```
<key>UberClientID</key>
<string>MyClientID</string>
<key>UberCallbackURI</key>
<string>MyCallBackURI</string>
```

Not sure what to put in UberCallbackURI but followed a tutorial in the link:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Also I have in appDidFinishLauncing following setting configured:

```
Configuration.setSandboxEnabled(true)
```

Just put a simple button to call uber.

```
    let behavior = RideRequestViewRequestingBehavior(presentingViewController: self)
    behavior.modalRideRequestViewController.rideRequestViewController.delegate = self
    // Optional, defaults to using the user’s current location for pickup
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: 37.787654, longitude: -122.402760)
    let parameters = RideParametersBuilder().setPickupLocation(location).build()
    let button = RideRequestButton(rideParameters: parameters, requestingBehavior: behavior)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

I have also implemented following delegates in viewController :

```
extension ViewController : RideRequestViewControllerDelegate {
    func rideRequestViewController(rideRequestViewController: RideRequestViewController, didReceiveError error: NSError) {
        let errorType = RideRequestViewErrorType(rawValue: error.code) ?? .Unknown
        // Handle error here
        switch errorType {
        case .AccessTokenMissing:
            print("Access Token Missing")
            break
        // No AccessToken saved
        case .AccessTokenExpired:
            print("Access Token Expired")
            break
        // AccessToken expired / invalid
        case .NetworkError:
            print("Network error")
            break
        // A network connectivity error
        case .NotSupported:
            print("Not Supported")
            break
        // The attempted operation is not supported on the current device
        case .Unknown:
            print("Unknown")
            break
            // Other error
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button the SDK sends me to loginscreen in UBER. When I sign in.

It always prints 'Access Token Missing ' which is from the delegate.

Can someone help me?

Comment: And what line of code is printing that message?

Comment: @SevenBits check RideRequestViewControllerDelegate method (switch cases)

Comment: It's due to an error handled in Switch Case . The delegate is giving errorType .AccessTokenMissing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the login is failing. I think your problem has to do with your UberCallbackURI. On the **Authorizations** tab in the [developer dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/) you need to set a redirect URL. You need also put this as the value for **UberCallbackURI** in your `Info.plist`.

I would suggest using a unique url scheme that is specific to your app (as described in the link you provided)

Comment: No it didn't work! I set the url scheme for the app and set the redirect URI from developer dashboard in Uber as well.  I set the URI as someScheme://test in developer dashboard. used same in app. When I open the URI someScheme:// from safari it opens, but with uber it doesn't work.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha I had the same problem today and his answer solved my  issue, check agai that you are setting the callbackURI in the Authorizations tab and not the settings

Comment: Hello Grace. Can you share me the screenshots of your Info.plist and developer dashboard?

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha make sure that they exactly match. In your app you need to have the whole URI, not just the scheme. so your value should be "someScheme://test" for example

Comment: @JohnBrophy Thanx a ton. This is what I was missing. :)